# How can I make the program continue?

Tags: python

I'm very new to programming and python. The goal of this program is to display the users sentence as a triangle upon output. What I have so far is this

```py
def main():
  enteredSentence = input('Enter a short sentence: ')
  count = 0
  return enteredSentence, count


#prints the sentence in a triangle from first letter to full sentence
def UP(enteredSentence,count):
  for count in (enteredSentence):
    count = count + 1
  print(enteredSentence[0:count])
  print(enteredSentence)

# prints the sentence in a triangle from full sentence to first letter
def Down(enteredSentence, count):
  for count in enteredSentence:
    count = count - 1
  print(enteredSentence [0:count])


# prints out a message with the total count of letters printed.
#def Count():
main()
```

The program runs, but it only accepts input and then stops

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your code.

Comment: First of all, improve your title please. The variables inside the functions are visible only inside them. You need to pass as argument  or declare outside all functions.

Comment: the code under _# does work_ is working as it is on the extreme left side which means it is not bound to any function and therefore, it will be always executed.
But overall, this code will not work as you have left the body of countTotal() function empty, some statements are not properly intended. 
I would suggest, first try to understand the basics of functions in python.

Comment: Hi, your function does not work because it does not see "enteredSentence". How about trying this for a start def Down(enteredSentence):

Comment: @StupidWolf, thank you for the information, I also added count to the function as well. For example, def Down(enteredSentence, count): 
It cleared up the undefined errors and has changed them to "unused". 
Do these need to be returned in order to have them as used?

Comment: a bit confused about what you mean. Maybe edit your post with the new code? and also state what you would like as your output

Comment: @StupidWolf the errors have stopped but the code itself only accepts the input and then quits

Comment: You were counting the letters using count. Check the answer and compare with your code. Read with attention the traceback.

Comment: @Raphael upon comparison my understanding now is that I was not properly passing my variables to their functions from main. Can you briefly explain how count+=1 differs from count = count +1? or are they basically the same thing?

Comment: The problem was in `for count in input_sentence:` now is `for letter in input_sentence:`. letter is a str, you were trying to increment str and not int. Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer if it helped you. Also, discuss in the comments from the respective answer please to keep things organized.

Comment: @Raphael thats what I get for attempting this with no debug lines haha. Well, I really appreciate the time you and StupidWolf took to help. As a beginner its good to learn these things early before I continue. I'll keep careful note and be sure to have more "pythonic" code. Thanks again!

Comment: @Raphael I have 11 rep so it still records the upvote but isn't displayed publicly until 15

Comment: OK, don't worry. But you can accept the answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. It's important so others know that the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    input_sentence = input('Enter a short sentence: ')
    count = 0
    up(input_sentence, count)
    down(input_sentence, count)


# prints the sentence in a triangle from first letter to full sentence
def up(input_sentence, count):
    for letter in (input_sentence):
        count += 1
        print(input_sentence[0:count])
    print(input_sentence)

# prints the sentence in a triangle from full sentence to first letter
def down(input_sentence, count):
    for letter in input_sentence:
        count -= 1
        print(input_sentence[0:count])


# prints out a message with the total count of letters printed.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which Yields:

```
$ Enter a short sentence: hello


h
he
hel
hell
hello
hello
hell
hel
he
h
```

I left the code more "pythonic". Take a look [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/)